# Set value of 1st input into 2nd input when using antd table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, tags, antd

I'm using a search box and a button to filter AntD table. I want to use value(which an end user will enter) of textbox in button's onClick event. Actually, I want to filter data on basis of what an end user enters. If the input value matches then filter will work and vice-versa. I'm here to get help for getting value of textbox and setting it into button's onClick event.

Here's code below:

```
<div>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search here" style={{ marginBottom: 8, marginRight: 8 }} />
      <input type="submit" value="Search" onClick={() => { const searchedName = setsearchedName(student.filter(obj => obj.name.match(***HERE I WANT TO SET USER'S INPUT***) ? true : false)) }
      } style={{ marginBottom: 8 }} />
      <Table columns={columns} dataSource={searchedName} />
    </div>
```

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
const yourComponent = () => {
   const [text, setText] = useState("")
   const [searchedName, setSearchedName] = useState("")

   const handleSubmit = () => {
       setSearchedName(
           student.filter(obj => obj.name.match(text))
       )
   }

   return (
     <input value={text} onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)} />
     <input type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit} /> 
   )
}
```

you just have to set the value of the first input as a state and use it in you `handleSubmit` method.

**NOTE:**
you dont have to use ternary operator when you want to return true or false on a method that returns a boolean. you can just return the method like:

```
obj.name.match(text) // returns a boolean value
```

Comment: PRSHL, this worked fine and thanks for this. But search is getting done only case-sensitive. I tried to use 'localeCompare' but failed.

Comment: to avoid case sensitivity you could just match both strings with `obj.name.toLowerCase() === text.toLowerCase()`, I think the `match` function is overkill when not using RegEx.

Comment: you're welcome. feel free to mark my answer with the green checkmark if you want to :)